# Is our souls, angles never destroyed when it create or why Allah does not finish devil when he disrespect the order of Allah?

Tags: allah, islamic-philosophy, soul

My question is as we know that our body is nothing we are just because of our soul . Devil (iblees) disrespect the order of Allah and does not prostrate Adam (A.S). As we know that Allah is one and he create every single thing for us .He is a best creator .He create our souls and put our soul in a statue .My question is as we know everything is in the hand of Allah why Allah does not finish devil at the moment when hi disrespect the order of Allah ? Is devil ,angles or our souls never destroyed when it create first?

Comment: Maybe he wanted to punish him instead.

Comment: Rest of your question which is probably not answered by the above question, seems unclear.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should know that if Allah destroyed the Devil, the evils would not be destroyed, because there is something in our soul — actually a part of our soul — which orders us to disobey Allah. Even if Devil were destroyed, evil would continue.

Second, it's better to know that Iblees was not created as the Devil. He would utter prayer along with the angels, and Allah took great pride in him. When Iblees wanted to become the Devil, he asked Allah for three things as a gratuity for his goodness and prayers, one of which was to be alive until Doomsday and Allah accepted. In addition to what has been said before, it's better to know he will die in Doomsday, but our soul and also angels will be never ever destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

This life is a test for us. Satan failed his test. We should try to pass the test by obeying Allah and by following  Prophet Muhammad S.A.W and should die as believers.